# case-sensitivity in UNIX and Bash

Tags: bash, unix, case-sensitive, cd

If UNIX is case-sensitive, and I have a directory named ruby in my home directory, and no directory named Ruby, why do

```
cd ruby
```

and

```
cd Ruby
```

produce the same result, that is I cd into the ruby directory?

Comment: Some file systems (notably, HFS+) are case-preserving; the case used to create a file or directory is remembered, but any case is allowed for accessing it. That is, `mkdir ruby` creates the directory with all lower-case letters, but lookup allows any combination of case: `ruby`, `RUBY`, `RuBy`, etc. all match the same directory.

Comment: So is it the case with OSX 10.11.1? I can also type Mkdir or mkDIR instead of mkdir, and it does not give a "command not found" error.

Comment: Yes, OS X uses HFS+.

Comment: You can use Case-Sensitive (and Journaled) HFS+ on OS X if you really want "normal" UNIX behaviour.  That will involve creating a new partition, and you need to think it through carefully.  It is probably not worth it.  This is all down to the file-system, bash has nothing to do with it.  Program names (like `mkdir`) held on a case-insensitive disk are case-insensitive.  If you use `echo` it will use the shell built-in, but if you use `eCHo` then it will use `/bin/echo/`!  Be consistent with your case, otherwise you might get surprises.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that they are referring to the same directory. Check the output of:

```
ls [Rr]uby
```

If you are sure that they are referring to the same directory, then it could be `cdspell` builtin of `bash` that is working here, whose purpose is to correct minor typos in directory names while doing `cd`. In your case, it is correcting the cases of letter `R`/`r`.

You can check whether it is enabled by:

```
shopt cdspell
```

**Example:**

```
$ cd Ques
bash: cd: Ques: No such file or directory

$ shopt -s cdspell 

$ cd Ques
ques

ques$ shopt cdspell 
cdspell         on
```

Comment: if i type shopt cdspell, Bash says cdspell off

Comment: @A.N.Other Are you sure, they are the same directory? check the output of `ls [Rr]uby`?

Comment: 100% sure, ls ruby and ls Ruby give the same result. Same result happens if I create a new direcrory, e.g. newdir I can then cd Newdir and cd newdir

Comment: @A.N.Other: filesystem type?

Comment: OS X El Capitan 10.11.1

Comment: I think you're using HFS+, which is case insensitive

Comment: Instead of just `ls [Rr]uby`, I would suggest checking the output of [`ls -id1 [Rr]uby`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/ls/)... `-i` being the key here. The first number in output is the inode number. If that number is identical in all lines, then they represent the same files/directories & not 2 copies.